# Display columns that contain a carriage return

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, carriage-return

I have a `Students` table, which contains 7 address fields.

I need to display **1 row each for student** where the address fields have carriage return, if any.

It's confused after this.

The **9th column** (**1st column** - *Student ID*, **2-8 column** - *7 address fields*) must contain the list of column names which have a carriage return ( like addr_1, addr_3, 1 for each student ID separated by a comma)

The **10th column** must contain the **illegal character** (in this case, carriage return).

This code must be further extended to other illegal characters identified now and then and a report has to be generated.

I am unable to work on 9th and 10th columns. Can anyone help?

```
SELECT pty.id,
a.addr_1,
a.addr_2,
a.addr_3,
a.addr_4,
a.addr_5,
a.addr_6,
a.addr_7
FROM addr a 
inner join contact cON a.idf = c.add_idf
inner join pty ON c.pty_id = pty.id
WHERE 
INSTR(a.addr_1,CHR(13)) > 0 OR
INSTR(a.addr_2,CHR(13)) > 0 OR
INSTR(a.addr_3,CHR(13)) > 0 OR
INSTR(a.addr_4,CHR(13)) > 0 OR
INSTR(a.addr_5,CHR(13)) > 0 OR
INSTR(a.addr_6,CHR(13)) > 0 OR
INSTR(a.addr_7,CHR(13)) > 0;
```

Comment: let me guess, a front end app chokes on non printable chars, so the answer was "fix the data".  You'll constantly re-introduce these chars into the data, fix the app layer

Comment: You can use REPLACE f-n to replace CHR(13) with any other character in your query. Although it should work as is: SELECT INSTR('1'||chr(13)||'2', chr(13) ) str FROM dual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a homework question.  So, let me give you some hints:

(1) You can generate a table using syntax, such as:

```
select chr(13) as badchar from dual union all
select '!' . . .
```

(2) You can `cross join` this into the table and use a very similar `where` clause.

(3) You can then select the bad character from the table.

(4) You'll need an aggregation.

Actually, I would be inclined to drop the requirement of one row per student and instead have one row per student/bad character.  Here is an approach:

```
select a.id,
       a.addr_1, a.addr_2, a.addr_3, a.addr_4, a.addr_5, a.addr_6, a.addr_7,
       ((case when INSTR(a.addr_1, b.badChar) > 0 then 'addr_1,' else '' end) ||
        (case when INSTR(a.addr_2, b.badChar) > 0 then 'addr_2,' else '' end) ||
        (case when INSTR(a.addr_3, b.badChar) > 0 then 'addr_3,' else '' end) ||
        (case when INSTR(a.addr_4, b.badChar) > 0 then 'addr_4,' else '' end) ||
        (case when INSTR(a.addr_5, b.badChar) > 0 then 'addr_5,' else '' end) ||
        (case when INSTR(a.addr_6, b.badChar) > 0 then 'addr_6,' else '' end) ||
        (case when INSTR(a.addr_7, b.badChar) > 0 then 'addr_7,' else '' end)
       ) as addrs,
       b.badChar
from a cross join
     (select chr(13) as badChar from dual) as b
WHERE INSTR(a.addr_1, b.badChar) > 0 OR
      INSTR(a.addr_2, b.badChar) > 0 OR
      INSTR(a.addr_3, b.badChar) > 0 OR
      INSTR(a.addr_4, b.badChar) > 0 OR
      INSTR(a.addr_5, b.badChar) > 0 OR
      INSTR(a.addr_6, b.badChar) > 0 OR
      INSTR(a.addr_7, b.badChar) > 0;
```

It leaves an extra comma at the end of the column names.  This can be removed by making this a subquery and doing string manipulations at the next level.

To put all badchars on one line would require an aggregation.  However, I am not clear what the 9th and 10th columns would contain in that case.

Comment: Hi Gordon.. This is not a homework but something needed as a requirement for a client whom we work for..
How would I get the list of column names. Must be a separate package which query from all_tab_columns and stuff is needed. I'm totally confused. Could you kindly elaborate pls...

Comment: Good one Gordon.. Solution seems to be so simple. As its a weekend I can test it only on Monday.. Will let u know in case of any issues.
Lastly, yes u are right.. 1 row per id/character... :) :)

Comment: Might like to "where instr(a.addr_1||a.addr_2||a.addr_3 ... , b.badChar) > 0", and place the column most likely to contain a bad character first in the list

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon. This works perfectly !!!
With a little bit of tweaking to suit my requirements, I am able to get the results :)

Answer (score 1):

9th column would be with a `case when instr(...) then 1 else 0 end || case when instr(...) then`

```
create table tmp (vc varchar2(20),  vc2 varchar2(20));
insert into tmp values ('abcd','bcda');
insert into tmp values ('bcd','bcda');

select 
  case when instr(vc,'a')>0 then 'col1' else null end ||
  case when instr(vc2,'a')>0 then 'col2' else null end 
from tmp;
```

As for the second problem, you can just put `'RETURN'` in the 10th column. Since you are looking for only one forbidden character and get only lines which have it. 
When you come up with a solution dealing with several forbidden chars, I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

In similar situations I've gone for a Big Hammer and just detected non-printing control codes with a REGEXP_LIKE(col1,'[:cntrl:]'), because next someone will add a tab or something else that breaks the data.

Is it too much to ask that a check constraint be placed on the columns to prevent this from happening?